# jQuery Autocomplete Pull from Mysql Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

**What I'm trying to solve:**
User, inputs a zipcode like `08212`, or any US zipcode for that matter and `jquery UI Autocomplete` calls this source file: `../src/php/registration/getFanLoc.php`, that file does a query against the database for certain fields (described below) based on the zipcode entered.

**Have a form/jquery on index.php :**

*Assume that all the jquery UI code is already in this file*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('input#zip').autocomplete({
            dataType: "json",
            source: "../src/php/registration/getFanLoc.php",
            minLength: 3
        });
    });
</script>

<form method="post" id="FanDetail">
  <div class="ui-widget">
     <label for="zip">Zip: </label>
     <input id="zip" name="zipcode" value="US Zipcode" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />
  </div>
</form>
```

**the getFanLoc.php file** - that queries mysql for any records corresponding to the 5 digit zipcode entered:

```
     <?php
    try{
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['zipcode']); //////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        require_once('../../cfg/dbi.php') or die('Cant require dbi');
        $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
        $sth = $dbh->prepare(
        'SELECT fanDetLocID, fanDetLocCity, fanDetLocState FROM fanDetailLocation WHERE fanDetLocZip = ?');
        $sth->bindParam(1, $zip);
        $sth->execute();
    while ($res = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        foreach($res as $column=>$val) {
            $res[$i][$column] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
        }   
    print json_encode($res);
} 


    catch(PDOException $e){
        file_put_contents('../../../PDODBConnectionErrors.txt', 'ERROR: [getFanLoc.php] about '.$e->getMessage().'<br>', FILE_APPEND);  
    }



    ?>
```

I was originally having trouble, because it wasn't connecting to the database and `PDODBConnectionErrors.txt` had the errors, but I've since `FIXED` that part, and now it doesnt do anything, but now doesnt throw an error in the file either. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty newbie working with the `autocomplete jQuery UI widget`, so go easy on me :) .

**Changes I've tried:**

- Tried adding in the $_GET['zipcode'] above, since the commenter below thought this plugin used `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` . Changing it from $_POST to $_GET was correct, but now I face the below problem when trying to access the file directly:
- Also tried just accessing the file directly like `getFanLoc.php?zipcode=08039` this seemed to atleast get me a little closer . **The page now states ** `False` when I access it from this url, which makes me think my `while() foreach()` loop is erroneous. Does someone seem something strikingly strong with it?

To add: I am using this plugin: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ . Thanks @Sennet

**The FIXED While() loop (thanks to Sennett) works on direct access, but not on form:

```
    $jsonArray = array();
    while ($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $jsonArray[] = array(
          'label' => $result['fanDetLocID'], 
          'value' => $result['fanDetLocCity']);
    }
    print $jsonArray; // print results of array
    print json_encode($jsonArray); // json encode that array
}   // can't have code between here

// and here
    catch(PDOException $e){
        file_put_contents('../../../PDODBConnectionErrors.txt', 'ERROR: [getFanLoc.php] about '.$e->getMessage().'<br>', FILE_APPEND);  
    }
```

After 4 hours of working with Sennet, we now have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
```

{
    $('input#zip').autocomplete({

```
    dataType: "json",
    source: "../src/php/registration/getFanLoc.php",
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, args){
        event.preventDefault();
        var joinedValues = args.item.value;
        var id = joinedValues.split("|")[0];
        var cityAndState= joinedValues.split("|")[1];
        document.getElementById('actualZip').value = cityAndState ; 
            document.getElementById('zip').value = id;
    }
});
```

});

Comment: I believe that autocomplete sends the request via GET not POST.

Comment: So, do I need to just change line: `$zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zipcode']);` to use a `$_GET` var instead of `$_POST` ?

Comment: That would be the first thing I try to make sure I'm getting back the response I expect.

Comment: Can you please see the problem I'm having below in the other comments below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do would be to try accessing the file directly the webbrowser.  Leave it as `$_GET`.  What happens when you browse to `getFanLoc.php?zipcode=XXX` where XXX is a code known to exist?  Do you get any results?

Also, assuming you are using [this plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), you should return JSON and not a load of hyperlinks - the plugin will wrap them in HTML for you.

Comment: I tried accessing: `index.php?../src/php/registration/getFanLoc.php?zipcode=08139`, I do not get any results though. 

Could I change my while statement to be something like this:  `$sth->execute();
 while ($res = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $res = json_encode();
 } 
 echo $res;
} `

Comment: To specify: I am using that plugin.

Comment: @user9 Try going to `http://servername/src/php/registration/getFanLoc.php?zipcode=08139`, without the index.php.  If that reveals nothing, try some echo statements and at least get a hello world out of it, then look and see if there is any data in the database that corresponds to the zip code.  After that turn MySQL query logging on and see what queries are getting sent.  The trouble is that there are too many things that could be wrong, although I'm 80% sure that wrapping the results in an href will cause problems, because off the top of my head autocomplete requires a specific JSON response.

Comment: It's only worth looking at client-side code when the server is definitely returning something.

Comment: I've modified the php script to change that while loop. When I accessed getFanLoc.php?zipcode=08039 , it stated: `false` . Which is atleast a good sign that it liked the jQuery enough to zip on over the the php, what am I doing wrong in that loop? (Cross fingers, think we're getting closer here..) . Thoughts?

Comment: Does that false mean nothing exists for that zipcode or what?

Comment: To add: that zipcode in fact DOES exist in database, so what am I doing wrong with my while() foreach() loops ?

Comment: @user7 http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php - "returns false on failure".  `$i` does not mean anything - it is never initialised.  You should give it an value that increments with each loop of the `while` block.  Also, make a new array and write the column values to that, rather than writing them to the result of the `$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` call.  Additionally, print the results of the output array before it gets turned into JSON, and do some experimentation until it does what you expect.  `echo $var` and `print_r($array)` are your friends here.

Comment: So `$i` should be initialized prior to performing the `while()` ?

Comment: Please, see my proposed while loop, bit confused how I should implement this new $sth->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC) call .. ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9295/discussion-between-sennett-and-user975947)